# How to set action for open and close menubar in our iOS Application in SwiftUi?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menuitem, drawer

When I tap a menu button  the side menu is open, And when i drag to
for open then also works properly and when click outside of menuView
then does not hide the menu drawer.

This is menu View DrawerContent for navigation:

```
struct MenuView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical){
        VStack {
            
            
            
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "house")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                   
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "square.grid.3x3.fill")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                   
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
            
            
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "lightbulb.fill")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    Text("Plan")
                    .font(.title2)
//                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding(.leading,5)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
         
            
            
           

        }
        .padding(.leading,35)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.8,alignment: .center)
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is Home Page for drag gesture and on TapGesture and it works great. But my mind is blank that what code I should implement:

```
    struct UserHomePage: View {
    // The offset variable holds the offset to show or hide the menu.
    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var closeOffset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var openOffset = CGFloat.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        // Use GeometoryReader to get the screen size
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // Main Content
                NavigationView {
                    ZStack {
                      
                       
                       
                       
                        // Gray out the main content when the slide menu comes up
                      
                        Color.gray.opacity(
                            Double((self.closeOffset - self.offset)/self.closeOffset) - 0.1).onTapGesture {
              
                                print("Tap Gesture")
                            }
                            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                      
//                        }
                        FirstView()
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Alibrary", displayMode: .inline)
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                            self.offset = self.openOffset
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.headline)
                        }
                        )
                   
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                }
//                 Slide menu
                MenuView()
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.65)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                    // First, minus the value of offset for the screen width for the slide menu.
                    .onAppear(perform: {
                        self.offset = geometry.size.width * -1
                        self.closeOffset = self.offset
                        self.openOffset = .zero
                    })
                    .offset(x: self.offset)
                    // Set the animation of the slide.
                    .animation(.default)
            }
            // We'll implement the gestures
            // Set swipe thresholds to prevent users from unexpectedly appearing in menus
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 50)
                    .onChanged{ value in
                        // Reduce the value of the offset (menu position) according to the distance swiped
                        if (self.offset < self.openOffset) {
                            self.offset = self.closeOffset + value.translation.width
                        }
                      
                      
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        // If the end of the swipe is to the right of the start position, open the menu.
                        if (value.location.x > value.startLocation.x) {
                            self.offset = self.openOffset
                        } else {
                            self.offset = self.closeOffset
                        }
//                        self.offset = self.openOffset
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't understand how to implement the code for closing menu View
on click on outside of the Menu area

Please help me for design a Menu Drawer open close (for open click on
button and drag gesture. and for close drag gesture And click on
outside of menuView)

I am a native User of SwiftUI.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is Side Menu View

```
 struct MenuView: View {
        
        @State var shown = false
 
        var body: some View {
            
        
                ScrollView(.vertical){
                    
                    
                    ZStack {
                  
                        SideMeNu Items
            
            }
        }
```

> This is Main View and from here we can gesture and open and close side
> menu and open for drag and close for drag. and we can close the side
> menu on click outside of Side menu View

```
struct UserAct: View {
   
    @State private var offset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var closeOffset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var openOffset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var showMenu = false

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                // Main Content
                NavigationView {
                    ZStack {
                        VStack{
                            HStack{
                                Button(action: {
                                    
                                    self.offset = self.openOffset
                                    
                                }, label: {
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                    
                                })
                                
                                
                                Button(action: {
                                    
                                }, label: {
                               
                                
                                ZStack {

                                    HStack {
                                             
                                        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(.gray).fontWeight(.heavy)
                                        } else {
                                         
                                            
                                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").foregroundColor(.gray).font(.body).frame(width: 30,height: 30)
                                        }
                                        Text("search books..").foregroundColor(.gray)
                                        Spacer()
                                               
                                    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.5)
                                            .padding(.leading, 7)
                                        }
                                            .frame(height: 40)
                                            .background()
                                            .cornerRadius(8)
                                })
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                }, label: {
                                    Image("qr_c").resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                        
                                })
                            
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    
                                }, label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.system(size: 33))
                                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                                        .frame(width: 11, height: 55, alignment: .center)
                                        .padding()
                                        
                                })
                            }.padding(.leading)

                            .frame( width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.06)
                            
                            .font(.headline)
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            
                          
                            if self.offset == self.openOffset{
                                Color.gray.opacity(0.4)
//                                    Double((self.closeOffset - self.offset)/self.closeOffset) - 0.2).animation(.default)
                                    
                                    
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.offset = self.closeOffset

                                     
                                    }

                                
                                
                            }
                            else{
                                FirstView()
                       
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

                   
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                }

                
                MenuView()
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.65)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                     
                        .onAppear(perform: {
                            self.offset = geometry.size.width * -1
                            self.closeOffset = self.offset
                            self.openOffset = .zero
                        })
                        .offset(x: self.offset)
                      
                    .animation(.default, value: 0)
                
            }
           
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 50)
                    .onChanged{ value in
                       
                        if (self.offset < self.openOffset) {
                            self.offset = self.closeOffset + value.translation.width
                        }
                      
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        // If the end of the swipe is to the right of the start position, open the menu.
                        if (value.location.x > value.startLocation.x) {
                            self.offset = self.openOffset
                        } else {
                            self.offset = self.closeOffset
                        }
                        self.offset = self.openOffset
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```